# How to get the vertices positions of an instance

Tags: three.js

I'm using this code to create an instanced mesh, and a corresponding dummy Object3D (in an array), which allows me to manipulate each instance of the mesh individually. This all works fine.

What I now need to achieve is getting the geometry/vertices of each instance.

```
const parentGeometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 10, 10, 10, 1, 1, 1 );
const instancedGeometry = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry();

const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xFF0000 } )

THREE.BufferGeometry.prototype.copy.call( instancedGeometry, parentGeometry );

var defaultTransform = new THREE.Matrix4().multiply( new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale( 1, 1, 1 ) )
instancedGeometry.applyMatrix4( defaultTransform );

instancedMeshes = new THREE.InstancedMesh( instancedGeometry, material, instanceCount );
instancedMeshes.instanceMatrix.setUsage( THREE.DynamicDrawUsage );


// Creating a new dummy for each instance allows for individual control while retaining a single drawcall 
for ( let i = 0; i < instanceCount; i ++ ) {

    let dummy = new THREE.Object3D();
    dummyArray.push( dummy );

    dummyArray[i].position.copy( new THREE.Vector3( i*15-100,0,-100 ) );
    dummyArray[i].updateMatrix();

    instancedMeshes.setMatrixAt( i, dummyArray[i].matrix );

    instancedMeshes.instanceMatrix.needsUpdate = true;

}

scene.add( instancedMeshes );
```

For normal meshes within an array this works perfectly, however the geometry (somewhat unsurprisingly) is undefined for the instanced mesh.

```
let meshVertices = meshArray[i].geometry.attributes["position"].array;
meshArray[i].updateMatrixWorld();

// (Back) Top Left
let mesh_top_left_vertices = meshArray[i].localToWorld( new THREE.Vector3( meshVertices[15], meshVertices[15 + 1], meshVertices[15 + 2] ) )
```

How can I achieve the equivalent for the instances?